# Are people thoughts broadcasting on their brain-waves frequency?

Tags: neurology

Before my question, these are results I've gained when I researched about brain and neurons in couple of websites (plus my analysis!) :

(***It's not about reading thoughts through "monitoring brain waves"***)

> Brain is actually an organic computer that's always processing the
>   data that it gives from human body's sensors. Human brain includes
>   about 200 billion neurons with 125 trillion synapses in the cerebral
>   cortex. Neuron is an electrically excitable cell that processes and
>   transmits information through electrical and chemical signals.
>
> It's similar to wires of an electronic kit connected to a
>   power-source and electricity flows it's wires. Now it makes an
>   electrical field thanks to the electricity flows. That's exactly
>   what's happening in the human brain. So the human brain has also an
>   electrical field (like this kit) with an indicated frequency that's
>   different from person to person, cause the differences among people's
>   brains. And the process of thinking is : *transmitting electricity
>   among the neurons*.

**So it seems that our thoughts are broadcasting on our brain's frequency, like a radio-transfer module that transfers data on it's indicated radio-frequency.
In this case, it should be possible to get others thought using sort of receiver then re-broadcast it on our brain frequency.**

**It's like receiving others thoughts like kind of inception!**

Is it really happening ?
Has any research done in this scope ?

Comment: Your (unreferenced!) source doesn't claim thoughts are being broadcast. You seem to be speculating your own idea without evidence. It isn't fruitful for us to do the research on every idea people come up with, so we limit ourselves to the claims that are widely believed or are made by notable people.

Comment: Reference! => Wikipedia, High-School Physiscs, Some Search
But I still think that things are related to Brain + Tech are attractive and fruitful of course.
Because these can lead to somethings unexplainable.

Comment: I don't think I made myself clear. (1) You have formatted some text as though it is a quote, but you haven't said where it is from. You should always attribute quotes. (2) It is fine that you are interested in the brain. It is fine to wonder about how it works. It is fine to speculate your own ideas (although perhaps less fruitful than reading what others have found). However, this isn't the place to discuss those speculations. This is a place to discuss notable claims. Your claim is not notable; no-one else believes it.